# is it possible to call the view depend upon the page name in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect, extjs4.2

can anybody tell is it possible to call the view depend upon the page name in extjs4.1

Thanks

Comment: Your solution seems reasonable. Doesn't it work? If it fails, how?

Comment: @rixo it doesn't work

Comment: We need more information in order to help you. What about it doesn't work? Does it throw an error? Have you tried it without the pageName conditional? What class is `testpage` inheriting from and have you defined its alias correctly?

Comment: @Eric am getting error cannot read property 'items' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `callParent()` function inside `initComponent`.

Comment: i have update the code still getting error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined can u check whether am added in right place

Comment: You need to assign the items before doing `callParent`.

Comment: after assigned and called but am getting this error Ext.panel.Table.initComponent(): A column configuration must be specified

Comment: can you help in this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980913/how-to-call-second-application-view-from-first-application-in-extjs4-1